# WPF TreeView similar to Organizational chart with connecting lines

Tags: wpf, charts, treeview

I have modified my treeview to look like an Org chart using the example shown in the Code Project website (Author Josh Smith). I need connecting lines in the treeview to make it look exact to org chart. I found references pointing to the below site

http://wpfblog.info/2008/05/26/turning-a-treeview-into-an-org-chart-with-connectors/

But I am not able to view the content. Probably the webpage has been moved. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Way Back Machine web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20080710052830/http://wpfblog.info/2008/05/26/turning-a-treeview-into-an-org-chart-with-connectors/) I found this.

Comment: This Code is now included in Syncfusion WPF framework.